# How to configure a global zone along with two non-global zones in solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, solaris-zones

I have a SUN M3000 server. I want to configure this as a global zone (named z1dms) which will have two non-global zone (named zu9dms and zu10dms). Please tell me how to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zoneadm -z zu12dms halt`

`zoneadm -z zu12dms uninstall`

`zonecfg -z zu12dms delete`

`# zonecfg -z zu12dms`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> create -b`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> set zonepath=/data/zones/zu12dms`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> set autoboot=true`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> add net`

`zonecfg:zu12dms:net> set physical=bge0`

`zonecfg:zu12dms:net> set address=zu12dms/24`

`zonecfg: zu12dms:net> end`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> add net`

`zonecfg:zu12dms:net> set physical=e1000g1`

`zonecfg:zu12dms:net> set address=com1ank1/24`

`zonecfg:zu12dms:net> end`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> info`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> verify`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> commit`

`zonecfg:zu12dms> exit`

`#zoneadm -z zu12dms install`

`#zoneadm -z zu12dms boot`

`#zlogin -C zu12dms`

`locale: english`

`terminal: dec vt100`

`hostname: zu12dms`
`...`
`...`
`...`

Answer all the questions and configure the zone zu12dms
exit the console with ~.

`zlogin zu12dms`

Add im1dms in the trusted hosts files and run niss from im1dms to distribute the important files (shadow,group,hosts,trusted hosts files etc.)

`#svcadm disable sendmail`

Comment entry for /home in `/etc/auto_master`
Exit and reboot the zone

`zoneadm -z zu12dms reboot`

Answer (score 5):

A regular Solaris instance will provide you the global zone.

Using `zonecfg` and `zoneadm` you can configure and install zones

A typical zone creation is performed by:

```
#configure the zone
zonecfg -z zu9dms
create
#make some modifications if you want an alternate zonepath or autoboot for example
verify
exit
```

It is very important that the directory which will contain the zones is owned by `root` and that the mode is `700`

```
#install the zone
zoneadm -z zu9dms install

#boot the zone and enter the console of the zone
zoneadm -z zu9dms boot; zlogin -C zu9dms

#wait until SMF is configured and follow the system configuration assistant
```

For further reading I suggest you to read the `man` pages `man zonecfg` and `man zoneadm`